# Nx Angular: Jest encountered an unexpected token

Tags: angular, jestjs, nomachine-nx

My main app is giving me this error after testing.

I have seen this issue before but did not find any solution to it.

I have read somewhere that it is because of importing third party library but did not know
how to fix it

The failing message:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.   

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    C:\Users\7078\Desktop\angular-whitelable\node_modules\lodash-es\lodash.js:10
    export { default as add } from './add.js';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.mjs:5:23)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
```

And my testing code for the main application is the following:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from './core/angular-material.module';

import '@angular/localize/init';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                AngularMaterialModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                CommonModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
            ],
            declarations: [AppComponent],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create the app', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

My main application jest config

```
/* eslint-disable */
module.exports = {
    displayName: 'dashboard',
    preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
            stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
        },
    },
    coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/dashboard',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|mjs|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],
    snapshotSerializers: [
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
    ],
};
```

And the default jest config for the whole workspace

```
import { getJestProjects } from '@nrwl/jest';

export default {
  projects: getJestProjects(),
};
```

My core library is doing testing just fine

```
nx run core:test


 RUNS   core  libs/core/src/lib/services/range-selection.service.spec.ts
 RUNS   core  libs/core/src/lib/services/discount.service.spec.ts
...

Test Suites: 1 failed, 15 passed, 16 total
```

the jest config for the core libreary:

```
/* eslint-disable */
export default {
    displayName: 'core',
    preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test-setup.ts'],
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
            stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
        },
    },
    coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/libs/core',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|mjs|js|html)$': 'jest-preset-angular',
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],
    snapshotSerializers: [
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',
        'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
    ],
};
```

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~14.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.5",
        "@angular/common": "~14.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~14.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~14.0.0",
        "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
        "@angular/forms": "~14.0.0",
        "@angular/localize": "^14.0.7",
        "@angular/material": "^14.1.1",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~14.0.0",
        "@nrwl/angular": "14.4.3",
        "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
        "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
        "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^2.0.1",
        "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.1.0",
        "enhanced-resolve": "^5.10.0",
        "firebase": "^9.9.1",
        "highcharts": "^10.2.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "ng2-charts": "^4.0.0",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
        "subsink": "^1.0.2",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.6",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~14.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~14.0.0",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~14.0.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~14.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~14.0.0",
        "@nrwl/cli": "14.4.3",
        "@nrwl/cypress": "14.4.3",
        "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.4.3",
        "@nrwl/jest": "14.4.3",
        "@nrwl/linter": "14.4.3",
        "@nrwl/workspace": "14.4.3",
        "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
        "@types/node": "16.11.7",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.29.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.29.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
        "cypress": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint": "~8.15.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
        "jest": "^27.5.1",
        "jest-preset-angular": "^11.0.1",
        "ng-packagr": "~14.0.0",
        "nx": "14.4.3",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "postcss-import": "~14.1.0",
        "postcss-preset-env": "~7.5.0",
        "postcss-url": "~10.1.3",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.7",
        "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
        "ts-node": "~10.8.0",
        "typescript": "~4.7.2"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "16.x.x"
    }
```

Comment: What version of Nx and Jest are you running?

Comment: I have added my package.json deps